# How do I prevent Preview.app from confirming each time I click on a web link?

Tags: pdf, preview, ventura, links

Prior to MacOS Ventura, clicking on a web link within a PDF viewed in Preview.app would immediately open that URL in my default browser. Since upgrading to Ventura, however, clicking on such a web link pops up an interstitial dialogue asking me to confirm that I want to open this link in the browser.

Whilst I appreciate the security hand-holding *in principle*, the fact is that I *always* want to open the link and, as somebody who opens quite a *lot* of links from PDFs in Preview, this additional step is just an irritation.

**Is there any way to turn this new behaviour off?** 
(Perhaps some hidden preference setting that needs a Terminal command to toggle on/off?)

Comment: A total lack of answers leads me to think that there is, in fact, *no* way to prevent the interstitial dialogue from popping up. If anyone can show otherwise, please do chime in with an answer. It's driving me crazy.